# Django rest framework generic view for multiple models

Tags: django-rest-framework

Is there a way of creating a generic view to be used by several different models? I have many models in my project and do not want to have to create a view and serializer for each of them.

Assume this is a simple solution but I have spent hours googling with no results.

Within the Django REST framework API guide [Generic views Examples](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#examples%20Examples) the following code snippet is shown:

```
url(r'^/users/', ListCreateAPIView.as_view(model=User), name='user-list')
```

Which suggests this is possible but the example does not seem to be complete (or my understanding is not complete).

This is my attempt:

url.py

```
url(r'^foomodel/', views.GenericViewSet.as_view(model = Foomodel) ),
```

views.py

```
class GenericViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
  model = User # this is over ridden by the url 
  queryset = model.objects.all()
  serializer_class = BaseSerializer
  ordering_fields = '__all__'
```

serializers.py

```
class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = None
```

And of cause this fails as the serializer does not like model = None or any variation that I can think of.

Any suggestions as to how this should be addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be overriding the [`get_serializer_class`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#api-reference) method of the `ViewSet`.

The `model` field in the view will be fine as you override it in the url, as you said, what I would do is build the serializer class on the fly.

```
class GenericViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = model.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        class BaseSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
            class Meta:
                model = self.model
        return BaseSerializer
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You post was very helpful, but there were more issues once that one was addressed. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can i add an extra field to this serializer? I want to add a type field in serializer

Comment: return BaseSerializer.update({'type':'data'}) doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

To recap the intention is to create a reusable view that can be used for many models without having to repeat a heap of code. This leaves very little code in Django to create a backed API for many Django models. I am using this for ember.js

urls.py

```
from myapp import models as mymodels
url(r'^cs/(?P<strmodel>[A-Za-z]+)/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/', views.GenericViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve', 'post':'update', 'delete':'destroy' }, application = mymodels ) ),
url(r'^cs/(?P<strmodel>[A-Za-z]+)/', views.GenericViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list','post': 'create' }, application = mymodels ) ),
```

Worth noting that I have several apps and there is a different set of URL's to access them. The model being accessed is passed as `strmodel`

views.py

```
class GenericViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def __init__(self, application):
        self.application = application

    def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = getattr(self.application, self.kwargs['strmodel'] )
        request = super(viewsets.ModelViewSet, self).initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)   
        return request

    strmodel = None
    application = None
    model = User
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get_queryset(self):     
        return self.model.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):      
            class Meta:
                model = self.model
        return BaseSerializer
```

Hope this helps :)